# Ember - Within action, result is defined, returnvalue of same action logged in parent action is undefined? Why?

Tags: ember.js, undefined, ember-components

Quick and shortly I have following problem:

I have following two actions within a component in Ember:

```
createData: function(user) {
   let collection = [];
   for (let i = 0; i < user.posts.length; i++) {
       let data = this.send('createSingleData',user.posts[i], user, 'post');
       console.log(data);
       collection.push(data);
   }
   return collection;
},
createSingleData: function(data, user, type) {
   let entitySkeleton = {
          name: data.place.name,
          belongsTo: user.id,
          position: {
              data.place.location.longitude, 
              data.place.location.latitude
           }
         };
    console.log(entitySkeleton);
    return entitySkeleton;
}
```

the first log - within createSingleData, right before returning the logged value - writes the entitySkeleton as Object into the console - as expected.

However, the console.log(data) - within createData - writes 'undefined' to the console.

Is there any aspect of asynchrounosity I didn't respect?

P.S.:
I also logged any paramater within createSingleData, they are all set properly.
The variable collection also only gets pushed 'undefined'.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot return the value from action, instead you can set property from the action.

[how to return values from actions in emberjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20500823/how-to-return-values-from-actions-in-emberjs)

```
actions: {
    PrintSomething: function() {
        let obj = [{a: 'raj'}, {a: 'Prudvi'}, {a : 'thimappa'}]      
        console.log('before', obj);
        this.send('returnSomething', obj);
        console.log('after calling action', this.get('returnvalue'));
    },

    returnSomething: function(obj) {
        obj.push({a: 'FSDFSDF'})
        var data = obj;
        this.set('returnvalue', data);
   }
}
```

Comment: My Problem with this solution is, that I have multiple Actions which do calculations and therefore I need to return a value.

Comment: Is there a possibility to define a javascript function which can return values outside an action which is accessible within all actions?

Comment: you can write createSingleData as a javascript function in a separate js file and import that file, then call createSingleData that will return data.